# YA Novel: main character Juniper falls for her best friend's brother working together at a law firm

Tags: identification-request

I read a book where the female main character was named Juniper. She falls for her best friend's brother, but I forgot his name. They work together at a law firm, and he always calls her by different plant names. They meet again after a couple of years in a coffee shop. I don't remember the main male character's name or the book's title.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could this be *[Alive at Night](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/176148252-alive-at-night)* by Amelie Rhys?

The main female character is Juniper St. James, and she works at a law firm with her best friend's brother, Julian Briggs. He indeed calls her a variety of plant-based nicknames (Daisy, Willow, Lily, etc), and she asks him to pretend to be her boyfriend when she attends a wedding. From the Goodreads blurb:

> JUNIPER ST. JAMES has never met her half-sister before, yet she finds
> herself with an invitation to her lavish New York wedding. With only a
> handful of stressful weeks to go until the big event, Juniper wants a
> fake boyfriend, and she wants Julian’s help getting his college
> roommate and hot NFL star, Noah, to play the role.
>
> Julian reluctantly goes along with the trade, but spending long, late
> nights working on his case with Juniper makes him realize how
> surprisingly well he can tolerate her company. Or more than tolerate.
> And when Noah bails on being Juniper’s fake wedding date, Julian is
> ready to step in. But he promises himself he’ll never let her know how
> happy he is to stand by her side—even if just for one night.

Comment: I just found the epilogue available to read online, and confirmed that he also called her by many different plant names. So this has got to be it.